Algebraic Notation for Tessellations
Is there a numerical or algebraic way to describe the nature of tessellating certain objects? For example, take a simple 2D object like a square. Obviously this shape can tessellate space as you can stack them side by side and top to bottom. However, as shapes get more complex, is there a more rigorous way of denoting the manner in which shapes tessellate with themselves? Perhaps some sets or vectors representing the positions of each shape and the corresponding rotation?
An example for describing the tessellation of the unit square could be the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 1\end{bmatrix}$
where the tessellation is essentially the set of all unit squares with positions denoted by $\begin{bmatrix}1 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} m \\ n \end{bmatrix}$ for any integers $m$ and $n$.
Similarly for a rectangle of width 2 and height 1, we could write the set of all vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}2 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} m \\ n \end{bmatrix}$ as the definition of the tessellation.
One more example for regular hexagons:
$\begin{bmatrix}0 \ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ 1 \ \frac{1}{2} \ -\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2 \\ k_3 \end{bmatrix}$
This clearly will get a lot more complicated with shapes that require rotations, but I believe a similar principle can be applied with angle vectors as well.
Does a better version, or some standardized method exist for writing forms of tessellations mathematically? During some of my own research, I saw lots of group theory which I do not fully understand yet. The main reason I would like to know of a formal way of describing tessellations with numbers or vectors is to try to understand how they can be generalized in higher dimensions. Any advice would be helpful.

You might be interested in the wallpaper groups and their higher-dimensional generalization, space groups.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629741/coordinates-of-a-plane-tiling
